# PHP mail() with Reply-To not sending when gmail or hotmail

Tags: php, email, gmail

I'm making a contactform but the email won't send to the webmaster when the email that requested the contact is @gmail, @hotmail, @msn and maybe some more.

Here is my code:

```
//FROM CONTACTFORM:
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email']; //If this is gmail, hotmail it won't sent. 

//This is sent to the webmaster so he can answer:
$to = 'webmaster@mysite.com';

$headers = 'From: Mysite.com <webmaster@mysite.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: '. $to . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email . "\r\n"; //This is where it goes wrong
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$mailSubject = '[Contactform] - '.$subject.'';
$mailContent = 'MyMessage';

if(!mail($to, $mailSubject, $mailContent, $headers)) {
    echo 'Mail not sent';
}
```

The reply-to cannot be @hotmail, @gmail or @msn because then it won't send, i'll get 'Mail not sent' in this case.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Use [phpMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

Comment: Many email provider will check your mail server for authentication, so you'll probably need a real smtp or imap server.

Comment: but i should still be able to sent in the first place without receiving the 'Mail not sent' message? And i'm using real addresses to test. If i use an existing emailaddress that is like name@mysite.com it works.

Comment: Check the logs (both error logs and email logs) and post the relevant information

Comment: Error logs are clean, email logs i can't find.